# Can't run IOS after expo eject, see only white screen, how to make it work?

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, react-native-ios

I did expo eject, installed pods in IOS, and when I'm building app through Xcode, it says that build successful, however, when IOS simulator opens I see only white screen and error in Xcode

> `" **libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type
>   NSException**"`

,  It also says in the official documentation that "Once it's running, the iOS app should automatically request your JS bundle from the project you're serving from Expo CLI.", but nothing is happening!

How to fix this problem?

Here is the full stack of error:

```
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGABRT
    frame #0: 0x0000000110efa23e libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 10
    frame #1: 0x0000000110f4dc1c libsystem_pthread.dylib`pthread_kill + 285
    frame #2: 0x0000000110cbcc45 libsystem_c.dylib`abort + 127
    frame #3: 0x0000000110a4a5b1 libc++abi.dylib`abort_message + 231
    frame #4: 0x0000000110a4a74d libc++abi.dylib`default_terminate_handler() + 265
    frame #5: 0x000000010e193a9d libobjc.A.dylib`_objc_terminate() + 97
    frame #6: 0x0000000110a5665e libc++abi.dylib`std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 8
    frame #7: 0x0000000110a566d3 libc++abi.dylib`std::terminate() + 51
    frame #8: 0x000000010e193a22 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_terminate + 9
    frame #9: 0x0000000110b61616 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 28
    frame #10: 0x0000000110b64b78 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 301
    frame #11: 0x0000000116965ba8 FrontBoardServices`__FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 30
    frame #12: 0x0000000116965860 FrontBoardServices`-[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 457
    frame #13: 0x0000000116965e40 FrontBoardServices`-[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 45
    frame #14: 0x000000010f9e8721 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    frame #15: 0x000000010f9e7f93 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 243
    frame #16: 0x000000010f9e263f CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1263
    frame #17: 0x000000010f9e1e11 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 625
    frame #18: 0x0000000111f4a1dd GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 62
    frame #19: 0x0000000118e1581d UIKitCore`UIApplicationMain + 140
  * frame #20: 0x00000001054e9490 civic-champs`main(argc=1, argv=0x00007ffeea716ff8) at main.m:8
    frame #21: 0x0000000110bd7575 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
    frame #22: 0x0000000110bd7575 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
```

When I added exception breakpoints to the app, I see that it stops in this line of code:

[image]

Comment: which xcode version are you using?

Comment: Xcode version 10.1

Comment: `rm -rf /usr/local/var/run/watchman/ && brew uninstall watchman && brew install watchman` try to also check if your launch screen is integrated properly

Comment: Just have reinstalled watchman, the same result, well launch screen worked pretty well before expo eject, and it works okay on Android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, I think that the problem was that I didn't run `expo start`, before doing `pod install`. I cloned project once again and did `pod install` after `expo start` and  this problem disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell, because stack trace is very limited, but it sounds like [this](https://forums.expo.io/t/new-project-ejected-stuck-in-spashscreen/19458/11) error.

According to [the comment](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/2401#issuecomment-465657836), to resolve it, you should downgrade the `cocoapods`:

```sh
gem uninstall cocoapods
# Don't forget to press "Y" to remove executables
gem install cocoapods -v 1.5.3
```

Comment: I have already downgraded cocoapods to version 1.5.3 ,however, I’m still see white screen in IOS simulator and still get an error *libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type", however, thank for pointing to that issue, now I know that other people have the same error!